# How to analyze data with a column containing multiple values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm attempting to analyze idea submissions in Power BI where there is a column with multiple values separated by commas. Here is an example of the table layout (each row being a submission):

| Key | ... | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | Chat, Service, Dallas |
| 2 | ... | Banking, IVR, Miami, Zelle |
| 3 | ... | New York, Collections |
| ... | ... | ... |

The tags column has the data I'm trying to analyze and it's sorted in whichever order they are first entered in by the submitter so they don't follow a certain structure necessarily. Some submissions may have as little as 2 tags and some as much as 15. I'm trying to figure out a way to structure the data in a way that Power BI can analyze each tag (if that makes sense, I'm sorry I'm having a difficult time explaining).

For instance, I want to be able to see the number of submissions by department (like chat or collections). I know I can split the tags column and have a separate column created for each tag but the problem I run into is that the new columns created have different values in each row depending on the order. For example, the new table after splitting the tags column would look like this:

| Key | ... | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3 | Tag4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | Chat | Service | Dallas |  |
| 2 | ... | Banking | IVR | Miami | Zelle |
| 3 | ... | New York | Collections |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

As you can see, the Tag1 column has mixed values in the sense that row 1 and 2 contains a department (chat and banking) but row 3 contains a location (New York). I suppose the question I'm trying to ask is if anyone has any recommendations on how to better analyze the tags so I can answer questions like:

- What departments are sending in more submissions than others?
- Which site locations are sending in more submissions?

I appreciate any help and advice. I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest expanding to new rows rather than new columns.

[image: Split Column by Delimiter]

Then your data looks like this

[image: Result]

If you have a table of tags where each one is categorized as "Department" or "Location" or whatever, you can then merge that table onto the one above to have a nice Category column to help filter in your reporting.